# Show that a set is closed

Tags: general-topology

I have to show that this set is closed:

$\lbrace x \in \mathbb{R}^2 \vert \Vert x \Vert_2 \in [r,R] \rbrace$

Here $\Vert x \Vert_2 = \sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2}$ and $R≥r>0$.

I think that I have to use that the set is the pre-image of a closed set, but I'm not sure. Can anyone help?

Comment: you don't have to do that. how did you define open sets? i will give you a hint, you can represent that set as a intersection of two closed set's

Answer (score 0):

(1) The interval $[r,R]$ is a closed set in $\mathbb{R}$.

(2) The map $\|\cdot\|_2:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous.

(3) Preimages of closed sets under continuous maps are closed.

The set in question is the preimage of $[r,R]$ under $f(x)=\|x\|_2$.

If you cannot use/prove all of (1)-(3), it might be easier to directly show the complement is open.